# set datetimepicker in c# windows

Tags: c#, .net

how can i set date and time to `DateTimePicker` which is stored in `database` and which is in
"`2013-04-04 04:27:16.000`" format

The column in database is '`datetime`' format.

Comment: How far did you get while trying? Post some code to give context to where you're stuck.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me.  What are you trying to do, what are you expecting to see, and what are you observing instead?

Comment: i want to Edit Date which will show the current stored date from DB in datetimepicker, user can see the Date for that record in Datetimepicker and edit using same.

Comment: What database do you use? How do you connect to the database?

Comment: @Rik i m using Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a datetime string:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(DateTime));
var result = converter.ConvertFrom(dateTimeString);
DateTime value = (DateTime)result;
DateTimePicker.Value = value;
```

or use DateTime.Parse or TryParse

or you can get it from database as a DateTime

```
DateTime? dt =row.Field<DateTime?>(columnName);
if(dt.HasValue) DateTimePicker.Value = dt.GetValueOrDefault();
```

where *row* is a DataRow you got from your database